# If I import the World State from the Keep will it erase my game progress in DA: I?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I already started DA:I last night. But I did the Keep stuff just now. If I import my World State will it erase my current save from last night and will I have to restart my game or will it not affect my game save?

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not it affects your current save, I do not have enough evidence to come to a conclusion. However, importing a new World State will not erase your current save file.